# Auto update and redeploy docker containers in Portainer

Tags: docker, portainer

I am using Portainer to deploy my containers. I need it to:

1. automatically update the base images of my custom image and redeploy them
2. poll a docker registry (in my case Nexus) to check for newer versions of the custom image, pull that image and deploy it (all automatically).

Is there a way to achieve both of these requirements?

Comment: Did you figure out a way to accomplish this?